# How to import two input name into an array in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```js
class BankForm extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   onSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e.target.price.value);
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <AddForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
      );
   }
}

function AddForm(props) {
   return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
           <input type="number" name="price" />
           <input type="number" name="price" />
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

How to import two input name into an array in react

Please fix my code in console.log(e.target.price.value);

I tried it :

console.log(e.target.price.value[0]); x

console.log(e.target.price[0].value); x

This code will work well if there is only one price.

Help me!!! :C

Comment: Give your form fields different names, say, `price1` and `price2`. Turn their values into an array in `onSubmit`.

Comment: It is complicated if there is a lot of input
ex) price, name, contents ...

Comment: Users add input

Comment: so whatdoes `e.target.price` return? Also, why don't you just `map` the inputs? Seems smarter than having to copy each and every one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) what you should do is have a backing state field for your input values.  In react this is called a controlled input.  On change of each input you store that inputs value into state.  Since you want an array of prices then you need some state variable set to an array and then on each change of the input, store the new value in that state array.  On render you need to set the inputs value back again so that it will be visible.

```
class BankForm extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
     this.state = {
       price: [
         21,
         55
       ]
     };
   }

   onSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(this.state.price);
   }

   onPriceChange(index, e) {

     var prices = this.state.price.slice();

     prices[index] = e.target.value;

     this.setState({
       price: prices
     });
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
           <input type="number"  value={this.state.price[0]} onChange={this.onPriceChange.bind(this, 0)} />
           <input type="number"  value={this.state.price[1]} onChange={this.onPriceChange.bind(this, 1)} />
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      );
   }
}
```

in this example I defaulted the text box values by pre setting the array values but you can change that by using an empty array like this

```
this.state = {
           price: []
         };
```

each input has its onChange event wired to onPriceChange function.  That function just updates the state by making a copy of the prices array, then using the passed in index sets a new value.

```
onPriceChange(index, e) {

         var prices = this.state.price.slice();

         prices[index] = e.target.value;

         this.setState({
           price: prices
         });
       }
```

finally the onsubmit just prints the current state to the console

```
onSubmit(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log(this.state.price);
       }
```

I have a working [example on webpackbin here](http://www.webpackbin.com/Vycs_0pHM) you can play with.  I know, this seems like a lot of work if you have large forms but there is a library I like that makes this really simple called [formsy](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react).

Formsy wraps all this work up by using mixins and allowing you to build reusable form components like text boxes, combos, etc.  Place them inside a formsy form component and magically in the onsubmit event you have a nice model to work with so your code can look like this instead.

```
import Formsy from 'formsy-react';

  const MyAppForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return {
        canSubmit: false
      }
    },
    enableButton() {
      this.setState({
        canSubmit: true
      });
    },
    disableButton() {
      this.setState({
        canSubmit: false
      });
    },
    submit(model) {
      someDep.saveEmail(model.email);
    },
    render() {
      return (
        <Formsy.Form onValidSubmit={this.submit} onValid={this.enableButton} onInvalid={this.disableButton}>
          <MyOwnInput name="email" validations="isEmail" validationError="This is not a valid email" required/>
          <button type="submit" disabled={!this.state.canSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </Formsy.Form>
      );
    }
  });
```

in your form's submit handler formsy will give you a model generated from your input values.  Under the covers formsy is doing all the work to setup the backing state fields for each input type so you don't have to.

Comment: Thx for your kind answer

Answer (score 1):

In your case the `target` of the event is `<form>` and inputs are it's children, so in order to access their values you need to fetch the children. The simplest fix would be this `onSubmit` method:

```
   onSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     for (let i = 0; i < e.target.children.length; i++) {
            if (e.target.children[i].name === 'price') {
                console.log('value: ', e.target.children[i].value)
            }
     }
   }
```

[JSFiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/67178/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div id="app"></app>
```

,

```
/* In index.jsx */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class BankForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // This will go through every item with name 'price' and get for you
    e.target.querySelectorAll('[name="price"]').forEach((e, i) => {
      console.log('Value of', i, 'th Item is:',  e.value);
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <AddForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
    );
  }
}

function AddForm(props) {
  return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
          <input type="number" name="price"/>
          <input type="number" name="price"/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDom.render(<BankForm />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

output is

```
Value of 0 th Item is: 2
Value of 1 th Item is: 3
```